# RadWindow does not want to comply and stay within a restriction zone

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radwindow

I have a radwindow being called and its not wanting to have anything to do with staying or opening in a restricted zone for it.
I looked at the Telerik Demo's, and started from there. I followed the demo's and tried modifying the Radwindow to work the way I wanted it and it just doesn't work and I am not sure why or where I am going wrong. 
I have tried a couple different things for its restriction zone, but no matter what I have done, it won't stay where I want it.

The window opens on the event, but maximizes to the full screen and not in its zone.

Please pay no mind to the NavigationUrl of the menu, they were just there for testing earlier.

Here is the script for calling the window.

```
function OpenRadWindow() {
        var myWindow = window.radopen(null, "RadWindow Test");
        myWindow.center;
        myWindow.maximize();
    }
```

and here is my markup

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
    <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <div id="Nav" style="width: 250px; height: 100%; float: left;">
                        <telerik:RadPanelBar ID="RadPanelBar1" runat="server" OnClientItemClicking="OnAreaClick">
                            <Items>
                                <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Products" Expanded="true" runat="server">
                                    <Items>
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Search Product" />
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Add Product" />
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Update Product" />
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Delete Product" />
                                    </Items>
                                </telerik:RadPanelItem>
                                <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Vendors" Expanded="false" runat="server">
                                    <Items>
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Search Vendor" NavigateUrl="BrowseVendors.aspx" />
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Add Vendor" NavigateUrl="WebForm3.aspx" />
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Update Vendor" />
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Delete Vendor" />
                                    </Items>
                                </telerik:RadPanelItem>
                                <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Locations" Expanded="false" runat="server">
                                    <Items>
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Search Location" />
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Add Location" />
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Update Location" />
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Delete Location" />
                                    </Items>
                                </telerik:RadPanelItem>
                                <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="Receiving" Expanded="false" runat="server">
                                    <Items>
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem ImageUrl="Images/AddRecord.gif" Text="Search PO" />
                                        <telerik:RadPanelItem ImageUrl="Images/AddRecord.gif" Text="Receive PO" />
                                    </Items>
                                </telerik:RadPanelItem>
                            </Items>
                        </telerik:RadPanelBar>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="100%">
                    <div id="RestrictionArea" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid black; float: left;">
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlRestArea" Width="100%" Height="625px" runat="server" BackColor="Gray">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="RZone">

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" EnableShadow="true">
            <Windows>
                <telerik:RadWindow runat="server" ID="RadWindow1" Height="300px" Width="400px" RestrictionZoneID="RZone">
                </telerik:RadWindow>
            </Windows>
        </telerik:RadWindowManager>
    </div>
    <telerik:RadButton AutoPostBack="false" ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClicked="OpenRadWindow" Text="Open RadWindow" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the restriction id in the radwindow properties itself and not where it should have been. It was supposed to be in the radwindowmanager, now its there and working.

Comment: two tips: do not use spaces for the RadWIndow IDs, i.e., for the second parameter of radopen(), and two: do set your restriction zone size in pixels. Using percent may result in it changing dynamically with windows open in it, and this could lead to issues (what is the window supposed to do when its zone changes).